# Email based on the dropdown answer in a specific cell using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Below is code where I have all managers CCed on response email.

I'd rather the content of cell P2 ("Select Your Work Area") direct where that email gets CCed.
e.g. "Snow Camp (3-6)" gets CCed to Melissa's email address.

Sample Form:
[image: Sample Form]

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
On Error Resume Next
Set Wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Wb2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Select Case Wb.FileFormat
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbook:
        xFile = ".xlsx"
        xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled:
        If Wb2.HasVBProject Then
            xFile = ".xlsm"
            xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Else
            xFile = ".xlsx"
            xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        End If
    Case Excel8:
        xFile = ".xls"
        xFormat = Excel8
    Case xlExcel12:
        xFile = ".xlsb"
        xFormat = xlExcel12
End Select
FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
Filename = Wb.Name & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
Wb2.SaveAs FilePath & Filename & xFile, FileFormat:=xFormat
With OutlookMail
    .To = "DiscoveryCenterRentals@vailresorts.com"
    .CC = "melissa.s.evans@vailresorts.com;douglas.s.kaufman@vailresorts.com;David.Isaacs@vailresorts.com;" & Range("k7").Value
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "2024-25 Schedule - " & Range("E3").Value
    .Body = "Please be sure to save a copy of your schedule for reference." & vbNewLine & _
      vbNewLine & _
      "You can reach out to your Core Area manager after October 1st:" & vbNewLine & _
      "**Snow Camp - Melissa.S.Evans@VailResorts.com" & vbNewLine & _
      "**Mountain Camp - Douglas.S.Kaufman@VailResorts.com" & vbNewLine & _
      "**Privates & Adults - David.Isaacs@VailResorts.com" & vbNewLine & _
      vbNewLine & _
      "Thank you for submitting your schedule. Refresher weekend is November 2nd & 3rd. We hope to see you there!" & vbNewLine & _
      vbNewLine & _
      "***Think Snow***"
    On Error Resume Next
    .Attachments.Add Wb2.FullName
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
Wb2.Close
Kill FilePath & Filename & xFile
Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried to add code just below the "On Error Resume Next" line but I got an error. I was trying to trigger an email to Melissa but also add the employee's last name to the email subject line. I'm happy to remove the "submit" button if the email can be triggered another way.

```vb
Dim xRg As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("P2"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > "Snow Camp (3-6)"Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        With OutlookMail
            .To = "DiscoveryCenterRentals@vailresorts.com"
            .CC = "melissa.s.evans@vailresorts.com;" & Range("k7").Value
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "2024-25 Schedule - " & Range("E3").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Select Case` statement to set the `.CC` property dynamically based on the value of cell P2. You'll insert this logic right before configuring the email's properties (e.g., `.To`, `.CC`, etc.). Now to trigger the email based on cell changes, I would use a different strategy.

First, let's fix the `CommandButton1_Click` procedure to dynamically set the CC based on the dropdown in cell P2. Assuming cell P2 contains the name of the work area (e.g., "Snow Camp (3-6)"), you could do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Dim ccEmail As String
    
    ' Your existing setup code for the workbook, worksheet, etc.
    
    ' Determine the CC email based on the dropdown in P2
    Select Case Range("P2").Value
        Case "Snow Camp (3-6)"
            ccEmail = "melissa.s.evans@vailresorts.com"
        Case "Mountain Camp"
            ccEmail = "douglas.s.kaufman@vailresorts.com"
        Case "Privates & Adults"
            ccEmail = "David.Isaacs@vailresorts.com"
        Case Else
            ccEmail = "" ' Default or a fallback email
    End Select
    
    ' Your existing code to create Outlook objects
    
    With OutlookMail
        .To = "DiscoveryCenterRentals@vailresorts.com"
        .CC = ccEmail & ";" & Range("k7").Value ' Use the dynamically determined CC
        ' Your existing code for BCC, Subject, Body, etc.
    End With
    
    ' Your existing code to finalize the email and clean up
End Sub
```

For triggering an email based on changes to a specific cell (like P2), you would typically use the `Worksheet_Change` event within the sheet's code module, not within the same code as a button click event. This approach requires careful consideration, especially around user experience and potential for sending emails unintentionally. Here's a simplified example of how you might start that:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("P2")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Call your mail function here, or place a simplified version of the mail sending code directly here
        ' Be cautious with this to prevent accidental email sends
    End If
End Sub
```

Automatic email sends based on cell changes can lead to a lot of unintended emails if not carefully managed. Consider adding additional checks or confirmations before sending the email automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This determines the email address and `.Body` text based on the entry in P2.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Dim xOutlookObj As Object
'Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

' Commonly seen but appropriate in less than a miniscule number of cases.
'On Error Resume Next

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim ccText As String
Dim bodyText As String

With OutlookMail

    .To = "main@company.com"
    
    ' InStr is case sensitive.
    ' LCase is one possibility.
    ' Likely unnecessary with a dropdown.
    
    If InStr(LCase(Range("P2").Value), LCase("Snow")) Then
        ccText = "mgrSnow@company.com"
        bodyText = "Snow Camp - " & ccText
        
    ElseIf InStr(LCase(Range("P2").Value), LCase("Mountain")) Then
        ccText = "mgrMountain@company.com"
        bodyText = "Mountain Camp - " & ccText
        
    ElseIf InStr(LCase(Range("P2").Value), LCase("Privates")) Then
        ccText = "mgrPrivates@company.com"
        bodyText = "Privates & Adults - " & ccText
    
    Else
        Debug.Print "No match." & vbCr & "P2 Value: " & Range("P2").Value
        MsgBox "No match." & vbCr & vbCr & "P2 Value: " & Range("P2").Value
        GoTo cleanup
        
    End If
    
    .CC = ccText & ";" & Range("k7").Value
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "2024-25 Schedule - " & Range("E3").Value
    .Body = "Please be sure to save a copy of your schedule for reference." & vbNewLine & _
      vbNewLine & _
      "You can reach out to your Core Area manager after October 1st:" & vbNewLine & _
      bodyText & vbNewLine & _
      "Thank you for submitting your schedule. Refresher weekend is November 2nd & 3rd. We hope to see you there!" & vbNewLine & _
      vbNewLine & _
      "***Think Snow***"
      
    .Display
End With

cleanup:
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

`Worksheet_Change` is inappropriate, there would be many inadvertently created emails.